# How to get pandas pct_change to affect rows with a given index value independently from each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', 2],
    ['B', 4],
    ['C', 20],
    ['B', 8],
    ['C', 2],
    ['A', 2]],
    columns=['Label', 'Val1',])

print(df)


  Label  Val1
0     A     2
1     B     4
2     C    20
3     B     8
4     C     2
5     A     2
```

If I calculate the percentage change of `Val1`:

```
df['Val1_change'] = df['Val1'].pct_change(periods=1)
```

I get this:

```
  Label  Val1  Val1_change
0     A     2          NaN
1     B     4         1.00
2     C    20         4.00
3     B     8        -0.60
4     C     2        -0.75
5     A     2         0.00
```

Each row has the change according to it's value in relation to the previous value. Cool.

I would like however to calculate percentage change between rows that have the same Label value, so each value in a row that has Label `A` is calculated according the change in relation to the previous row with value `A`, and so forth.

So I would get this:

```
  Label  Val1  Val1_change
0     A     2         NaN
1     B     4         NaN
2     C    20         NaN
3     B     8         1.00    # 100% increase from previous B row
4     C     2        -0.90    # 90 decrease from previous C row
5     A     2         0.00    # no change from previous A row
```

I tried by setting Label as the index first:

```
df.set_index('Label', inplace=True)
df['Val1_change'] = df['Val1'].pct_change(periods=1)
```

But there is no change to the calculated pct_change:

```
Label                   
A         2          NaN
B         4         1.00
C        20         4.00
B         8        -0.60
C         2        -0.75
A         2         0.00
```

How can I accomplish this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `Label` and do `.pct_change()` over `Val1` column:

```py
df["Val1_change"] = df.groupby("Label")["Val1"].pct_change(periods=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Label  Val1  Val1_change
0     A     2          NaN
1     B     4          NaN
2     C    20          NaN
3     B     8          1.0
4     C     2         -0.9
5     A     2          0.0
```